# find a directory with most recent update and with a particular prefix in name

Tags: bash, shell, unix, directory

I have number of directories starting with same prefix (say foo123, foo345, foo234, foo456h,..)  in a particular directory.

Now I want to find directory with prefix foo which is created(modified) most recently. What would be best way to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very similar to the others

`ls -ltrd foo* | tail -1 | awk '{print $8}'`

or if you want the list do it without `awk`, `awk` is just returning the name

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -ltr | grep '^d' | awk '{print $8}' | grep '^foo' | tail -1
```

YF

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
 ls -tdF foo*|grep '/$'|head -1
```